# How to block an IP address?

Tags: macos, firewall, network

I am running MacOS Mojave. I am wondering if there is an easy way to block an IP address.

For example, I can `ping 8.8.8.8` and `telnet 8.8.8.8 53`. Now, I want to block all access to 8.8.8.8. so ping and telnet should both fail.

Btw, I’m not looking to use dns to this host. I can block it easily in `/etc/hosts` file but not all apps and services respect dns and hosts override. I’m looking for a non DNS block to implement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution by using PF.

### (1) edit PF configuration

```
sudo vim /etc/pf.conf
```

Append the following line to the file:

```
block drop from any to <IP Address>
```

For example: `block drop from any to 8.8.8.8`

### (2) Load the config by running

```
sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
```

### (3) Enable PF by running:

```
sudo pfctl -e
```

### (*) If you want to disable PF, run:

```
sudo pfctl -d
```

Comment: Quick follow-up question: when I load the config, I get a warning that "pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details." This is just enough to be alarming, but not enough for me to know if this problem applies or if in this case I am always reloading the main ruleset (your step 2), so everything is copacetic.